# CMake target_include_directories does not find #include of private header

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build a libary with the following directory structure:

```
lib1
|-include
| |-lib1
|   |-public.h
|-src
| |-private.h
| |-private.cpp
| |-public.cpp
|-lib
| |-liblib1.a
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

were the public header includes the private header to use its functionality.

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
project(math)

set(SRC_FILES src/private.cpp src/public.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_FILES})

target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
    PRIVATE
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src"
)

set_target_properties(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES 
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
)
```

But when I try to build the libary, I get an error from `public.h` saying that there is not file `private.h`

When googling I either find quite old posts that don't use `target_include_directories` or they support an unclean structure by putting all files in the same directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you include a header, then you must tell where that header is. If you say that the header is private, then you aren't telling where the header is to the dependencies. When the dependencies include the private header through the public one, they don't know where it is.

Solution: Make all headers included by a public header to be public. Or to phrase it another way: Do not include private headers in public ones.

Answer (score 2):

> were the public header includes the private header to use its functionality.

You can't do that. Think of it that way: If you were to make a binary-only release of your library, all you'd ship are the public headers and the resulting .a/.so files of your library, but not the private headers and .cpp files.

A user of your library that would try to include the header `public.h` then would get a compilation error because the private header included by `public.h` cannot be found since it wasn't part of the release.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But lets say i have a template class:
`template<unsigned int D> class vector`
but i only ever want the user to know about the class:
`class vector2 : vector<2>`
that inherits from the template class.
Is there a way to hide the template?

Comment: @EvenLonger Partially. At minimum you need the definition of the class template so the compiler can know the size and alignment requirements. You can, however, only declare the member functions of the class template in a public header and move the implementation to a private header or source file. Then you can add an explicit instantiation declaration of the template `extern template class vector<2>`; in the public header where the class template is defined and the explicit instantiation definition `template class vector<2>;` in one of the .cpp file compiled into your library.